# Copying files from hard disk to LiveUSB

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb

I am very new to Ubuntu. I am using the latest desktop version of Ubuntu 12.04. I have created a live USB and booted in to my desktop.I want to copy files from my desktop hard disk to the live USB so that I can copy them back to my laptop hard disk.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the USB that you created persistent? Are you running Ubuntu from the USB, or you have it installed?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by any `USB`, but i don't think you will be able to copy files using live USB.

Ubuntu will auto mount your USB and show in the Home Folder `Devices` list.Copy and paste files just like you do in Windows or other OS.

Answer (score 0):

1. get a usb disk
2. Gparted and split the disk-> 1 fat32 and secondly "ntfs". (Name the ntfs part "suzy")
3. usb creator/bootdisk creator to make a live usb. (select the first fat32 part)
4. Disk will auto mount the ntfs in live as "suzy"

Answer (score -1):

If you make USB persistent so you can't copy files from my desktop hard disk to the live USB.
If you are running Ubuntu from USB you can't do it
If you have already setup your system then you can do it

Comment: Could you rephrase the first sentence? It is confusing. If the live USB has a persistent file then the changes you make and files you create will not be lost.